# Adding an Event Listener to Items in an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, jquery-events

Given an iframe with `<span class="fineme">` throughout the iframe...

Is it possible to add an event listener with jQuery to trigger an ALERT anytime the user moves their mouse over `.fineme` in the iframe, from the top/parent window?

Answer (score 6):

See http://api.jquery.com/contents/ for accessing content document of an iframe.

A solution to your question might be:

```
$("iframe#name").contents().find(".fineme").bind("mouseover", function() { alert("Found me"); });
```

Comment: Works for me. Maybe the class should be `.findme` instead of `.fineme`?

Comment: You may need to wrap this in a check to ensure that the iframe has loaded. If you try to access the contents before the iframe has loaded, you won't be able to find it. Wrap it in $("iframe#name").load().

Comment: +1 for waiting until load() - if you're writing the iframe contents programmatically (e.g. via `srcdoc`) it seems you always have to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, It seems that by default if you run a selector from the parent window it won't find elements inside the iframe. However, you can explicitly give jQuery the context in order to look inside the iframe.

One way to do this would be:

```
var iframe = $("#someIframeId");
$(".fineme",iframe.get(0).contentDocument).mouseover(function(){alert('hi')});
```

**NOTE:** This will only work if both the parent site and the IFrame are on the same domain.  For more information about this see: http://madskristensen.net/post/Iframe-cross-domain-JavaScript-calls.aspx

Comment: One thing to note:  for this to work your iframe must be on the same domain as your page.  If they are on different domains I think browser security my stop this from working.

Comment: This works fine for native jQuery, but what about jQuery UI objects? For instance, if you call resizable on the element, it won't have the mouse context. You have to click on the resizable handles and drag your mouse outside of the iframe for it to respond to mouse movements.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found a solution that works for me. Try this:

```
document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.$('.fineme').on( ... )
```

It works for any jquery functions, but listens for events on the iFrame dom's jQuery.